# Polynomial with $p$ dividing $q-1$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, polynomials, prime-numbers, divisibility

Does there exist a non-constant polynomial $P(x)$ with integer coefficients such that for any two (positive) primes $p<q$ with $p \mid P(x_1)$ and $q \mid P(x_2)$ for some (not necessarily distinct) $x_1$ and $x_2$ the relation $p\mid q-1$ holds? (Throughout, $a\mid b$ means "$a$ divides $b$".)

I guess there should be a simple way to solve it by only using $a-b \mid P(a) - P(b)$ but I could not find such. Any help appreciated!

Comment: I think that in general such a polynomial will not exists. Why? Because there will be infinitely many primes that divide $P(x)$ at some point $x$ and we don't have the property $p|q-1$ for all primes

Comment: @LegNaiB  −|()−() is a pretty famous result, and $2-0 = 2 \mid (5-1)$

Comment: Oh I messed up because I thought about $P(x)=x^2+1$ and $P(x)=x^2$ at the same time and thus got $2 | 5$ which is not correct. Sorry about that